# How can i see memory usage on linux?(last 30 days)

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, virtual-machine

I have some vms on Azure(Brazil) and i need to see last 30 day's memory usage. Log Analytics on't work in South Brazil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can deploy Azore Log Analytics in the nearby region from South Brazil and connect all VMs to the workspace to collect the logs.

Not sure if you can get the logs for your VM for last 30days.

However, if you want the logs to be collected with in South Brazil, then you have to follow as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

You can check in diagnostic settings by Enabling guest-level monitoring on existing VMs :https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/blog/azure-linux-vm-infrastructure-monitoring-and-diagnostics-2/ 
 Examples of extended metrics include \Memory% Committed Bytes In Use and \Memory\Available Bytes.

If the issue still persists, Please post your query in [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows)